# Ruby on Rails - Rspec - Controller test - nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I got a pretty basic controller test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::OrdersController do 

    describe "GET #order_detail" do 
        before :each do 
            new_admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
            sign_in new_admin
            @storefront = FactoryGirl.create(:storefront)
            @order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)

         end

         it "assigns the requested order to @order" do
             get :order_detail, { :storefront_id => @storefront.id, :order_id => @order.id }
             assigns(:order).should eq(@order)
         end

         it "renders the :show template" do
             get :order_detail, {:storefront_id => @storefront.id, :order_id => @order.id}
             response.should render_template :order_detail
         end
    end 
end
```

Which gets me the following error for both actions:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
    No route matches {:storefront_id=>"14", :order_id=>"1", :controller=>"admin/orders", :action=>"order_detail"}
```

From the routes.rb:

```
resources :storefronts do
  resources :orders do
    member do
      get :order_detail
    end
  end
end
```

I thought

```
get :order_detail, { :storefront_id => @storefront.id, :order_id => @order.id }
```

would be the right way to generate the route but unfortunately it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the routes generated by Rails using `rake routes` or `bundle exec rake routes` in the application root. I did the same resource set-up in a brand new rails app, and rake routes output is as follows (only for order detail route):

```
order_detail_storefront_order GET      /storefronts/:storefront_id/orders/:id/order_detail(.:format)                   orders#order_detail
```

As you can see, rails is expecting `:id` and not `:order_id`. Try changing `:order_id` to `:id` as the parameter key in your spec.